# transfer projects from vss 2005 to tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, visual-sourcesafe, windows-server-2012

I installed TFS 2013 on my Windows server 2012 and I would like to transfer my projects from vss to tfs.

I downloaded the vss to tfs tool from [microsoft tool][1], but I was unable to install it because of compability mode, error message: "Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try Setup again"

Comment: You tried to install the tool on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: yes , i installed the tool on another machine with win server 2008 , convert the projects , ans than moved them to the tfs 2013

Answer (score 0):

According to this Buck Hodges [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2012/11/09/new-tool-to-upgrade-from-visual-sourcesafe-to-team-foundation-server-or-service.aspx), you're not going to be able to do this in Windows Server 2012, and Microsoft isn't going to fix it.  See the following comment:

> ... unfortunately, it is blocked in the installer. Right now we don't
>   have plans to re-release it, so you would need to run it on Win7-based
>   OS.

Incidentally, the post also addresses the question of upgrading to TFS 2013.

> I would like to know if the upgrade tool will work with TFS 2013?

The [documentation](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/867f310a-db30-4228-bbad-7b9af0089282) only mentions TFS 2010 and 2012.  However, Hodges also addresses this:

> ... it should work with the caveat of what OS you install it on (see previous 
>   comment).

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was : i installed the tool on another machine with win server 2008 , convert the projects and than move them to the tfs 2013